# Error Starting Docker Daemon on CentOS 7

Tags: docker, centos7

I have CentOS 7.x machine, and I've installed Docker following [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-centos-7). After the installation I tried to start Docker by:

```
systemctl start docker
```

but got this error:

```sh
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Executing

```sh
systemctl status docker.service
```

I get:

```sh
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Sat 2019-03-09 14:09:57 EET; 2min 15s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 17216 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 17216 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 09 14:09:55 host systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 09 14:09:55 host systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Mar 09 14:09:55 host systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Mar 09 14:09:57 host systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 09 14:09:58 host systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for docker.service
Mar 09 14:09:58 host systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 09 14:09:58 host systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Mar 09 14:09:58 host systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

The out put of `journalctl -xe` is:

```sh
Mar 09 14:09:55 host systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Mar 09 14:09:55 host systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Mar 09 14:09:57 host systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 09 14:09:57 host systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has begun shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has begun shutting down.
Mar 09 14:09:57 host systemd[1]: Starting Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has begun starting up.
Mar 09 14:09:58 host systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Mar 09 14:09:58 host systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for docker.service
Mar 09 14:09:58 host systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Mar 09 14:09:58 host systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Mar 09 14:09:58 host systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Mar 09 14:10:22 host sshd[17227]: Connection closed by 211.192.203.145 [preauth]
Mar 09 14:10:37 host fail2ban.actions[1307]: NOTICE [sshd] Unban 118.172.229.184
Mar 09 14:10:40 host fail2ban.actions[1307]: NOTICE [sshd] Unban 209.141.59.249
Mar 09 14:11:28 host sshd[17238]: Invalid user team1 from 24.138.80.34
Mar 09 14:11:28 host sshd[17238]: input_userauth_request: invalid user team1 [preauth]
Mar 09 14:11:28 host sshd[17238]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Mar 09 14:11:28 host sshd[17238]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=24-138-80-34.nx.cgocable.ca
Mar 09 14:11:29 host fail2ban.filter[1307]: INFO [sshd] Found 24.138.80.34
Mar 09 14:11:29 host fail2ban.filter[1307]: WARNING Determined IP using DNS Lookup: 24-138-80-34.nx.cgocable.ca = ['24.138.80.34']
Mar 09 14:11:29 host fail2ban.filter[1307]: INFO [sshd] Found 24.138.80.34
Mar 09 14:11:29 host fail2ban.actions[1307]: NOTICE [sshd] Ban 24.138.80.34
Mar 09 14:11:31 host sshd[17238]: Failed password for invalid user team1 from 24.138.80.34 port 35452 ssh2
Mar 09 14:11:31 host fail2ban.filter[1307]: INFO [sshd] Found 24.138.80.34
Mar 09 14:12:06 host sshd[17244]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for no.rdns.ukservers.com [94.46.185.14] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Mar 09 14:12:06 host sshd[17244]: Invalid user danilo from 94.46.185.14
Mar 09 14:12:06 host sshd[17244]: input_userauth_request: invalid user danilo [preauth]
Mar 09 14:12:06 host sshd[17244]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Mar 09 14:12:06 host sshd[17244]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=94.46.185.14
Mar 09 14:12:06 host fail2ban.filter[1307]: INFO [sshd] Found 94.46.185.14
Mar 09 14:12:06 host fail2ban.filter[1307]: INFO [sshd] Found 94.46.185.14
Mar 09 14:12:07 host fail2ban.actions[1307]: NOTICE [sshd] Ban 94.46.185.14
Mar 09 14:12:08 host sshd[17244]: Failed password for invalid user danilo from 94.46.185.14 port 59372 ssh2
Mar 09 14:12:09 host fail2ban.filter[1307]: INFO [sshd] Found 94.46.185.14
Mar 09 14:12:26 host fail2ban.actions[1307]: NOTICE [sshd] Unban 92.222.181.159
Mar 09 14:12:35 host fail2ban.actions[1307]: NOTICE [sshd] Unban 103.230.243.192
```

`sudo /usr/bin/dockerd -D -H fd://`

```
`Failed to load listeners: no sockets found via socket activation: make sure the service was started by systemd`
```

also after 'dockerd' command I get it:

```
`FATA[2019-03-09T16:47:09.490831472+02:00] Your Linux kernel version 2.6.32-042stab134.8 is not supported for running docker. Please upgrade your kernel to 3.10.0 or newer.`
```

OS info by `cat /etc/os-release`:

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

kernel version by `uname -r`:

`2.6.32-042stab134.8`

Comment: no evidence from your logs. please post `sudo /usr/bin/dockerd -D -H fd:// ` log output.

Comment: please check edited post, but I guess my kernel version is not supported by docker

Comment: good catch for kernel version issue.

but the real one is that centos 7 is based on kernel 3.10, so you are not running a centos 7, but most probably centos 6. please post `cat /etc/os-release`

Comment: Very strange it looks like Centos version is 7 but kernel 2.6, sse updated post

Comment: and maybe answer is there https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411732/why-is-my-centos-7-4-on-kernel-2-6-32

Comment: fine. you have your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run Docker on an OpenVZ "virtual machine", as it is not actually a virtual machine, but a (very old type of) container itself.

You will need a new VPS provider, which does not use OpenVZ or its commercial version Virtuozzo.